# MOC - Mit Out Computer

Tags: creativity

Anybody got any fun ideas for non-computer based sound design?

Got a long weekend coming up with plenty of spare time.  I'm planning on playing with my reel to reel to do some tape feedback stuff.

I've got guitars, a bass, pedals, keyboards, and an electric piano.  I'm going to mess with them, but has anybody come across and cool/fun/weird/noisy/frightening combinations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about…recording the entire weekend…processing it with a time stretch plugin into 4 minutes.

Comment: Best. Answer. Ever.

Comment: That'd be what, 72 hours?  About a gig an hour at 24/96.  So somewhere around 70 to 80 gigs?  Oh, this is happening...

Comment: However, that would in every way require a computer...  meh, it's too good an idea to pass up.

Comment: @ g.a.harry - please post when you're done!

Comment: you need a computer to record??

Answer (score 5):

Fun I usually have with sound design away from the computer:

- The thrift store and urban re-use stores are my personal favorite "gear shops."
- A soft percussion mallet, a contact mic, and a field recorder can keep me out of the studio and entertained all day.
- Rubber, water, and panes of glass can be combined for endless hours o' fun.
- Real instruments are far richer than virtual ones, even as fun as software is.
- In urban areas, a telephone pickup coil can capture all sorts of wacky RF shenanigans.
- My new favorite toy is a pocket-sized shortwave radio. Some crazy stuff out there in the ether.
- Testing the limits of the human voice (hard to do if anyone's around!).
- Taking a hike or bike, going somewhere nice, sitting and listening. I'm just as happy to come away with ideas, inspirations, insights, or rejuvenation as opposed to actual usable sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Toy shop! Look around the local toy shop for interesting objects. Maybe try constructing mechanical objects that make sounds and build your own kit of "sound objects"?

Or: for sounds that you would approach to design with plugins, try and create them with objects around you or with your voice. Think outside the screen!